# Number of transitions in a wave in verilog

Tags: verilog

How do I find the number of transitions in a square wave in one time period? Edge detection might miss out edges so the number of transitions using Verilog?

Comment: What makes you think 'Edge detection might miss out edges'? It would be useful to show what you have tried and why you think it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood, it sounds like you are trying to detect a signal with a data rate that is faster than your clock. If this is the case then it is not possible. You are basically seeing a glorified version of aliasing.

If, however your clock is faster than the signal you are trying to detect edges in then something like this should work:

```
module Edge_Counter(
    // Inputs
    input               Clock,      // System Clock
    input               Reset,      // System Reset
    input               Enable,     // Enables the detection of edges
    input               Signal_In,  // Monitored signal
    // Outputs
    output  reg [7:0]   Edge_Count  // Number of edges in monitored signal while enabled
    );

reg [1:0]   Next_Edge_Detection, Edge_Detection;
reg [7:0]   Next_Edge_Count;

always @( posedge Clock, posedge Reset ) begin
    if ( Reset ) begin
        Edge_Detection  <= 2'd0;
        Edge_Count      <= 8'd0;
    end else begin
        Edge_Detection  <= Next_Edge_Detection;
        Edge_Count      <= Next_Edge_Count;
    end
end

always @ * begin
    Next_Edge_Detection     = { Edge_Detection[0], Signal_In };
    Next_Edge_Count         = Edge_Count;

    if ( Enable ) begin
        if ( Edge_Detection[0] != Edge_Detection[1] )
            Next_Edge_Count = Edge_Count + 1'd1;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Also, as a side note, if you are just starting out with Verilog and your tools support use of System Verilog I would strongly recommend reading up on it and giving it a try. It will let fewer latches and other errors in your code fall through the system.